# reference to an element in a list in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a File and I want to get the Directory

My mongo table Directory is built this way:

```
0
   _id
   _class
   listOfFiles[2]
                -0
                      $ref       File
                      $id        idmongodb1   
                -1
                      $ref       File 
                      $id        idmongodb2 
1
   _id
   _class
   listOfFiles[1]
                -0
                      $ref       File
                      $id        idmongodb3
```

And I would like to know how to get the way to the idmongodb(1 or 2 or 3)

Can my query :

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(
            new Criteria().andOperator(

            Criteria.where("listOfFiles.$id").is(new ObjectId(file.getId()))
            )

    );

    return  mongoTemplate.findOne(query,Directory.class);
```

work ?

I would like to have confirmations.

In my JavaCode, the corresponding class Directory is buid this way

```
  public class Directory{

       public List<File> listOfFiles;   

 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query

```
 Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(
        new Criteria().andOperator(

        Criteria.where("listOfFiles.$id").is(new ObjectId(file.getId()))
        )

);

return  mongoTemplate.findOne(query,Directory.class);
```

actually works

Answer (score 1):

Try `$elemMatch` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch) for querying elements within a collection.